# ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined at generatePassword (tutor.js:103)at HTMLButtonElement.writePassword (tutor.js:113)

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, I've never come across the Violation error before. Not really understanding what is going wrong. I'm learning so any helpful hint would be awesome.

I'm sure that all of this should work just not sure where i'm going wrong at the moment.

```
var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");

function getOptions() {
    
// Creating a random element from selected array
function generatePassword() {

    // Looping through to create a new password

    for (var i = 0; i < userOptions.length; i++) {
        newPassword.push(getRandomElement(masterArr));
        
    };
    console.log(newPassword);
    return newPassword;
};

// Write password to the #password input
function writePassword() {
    var password = generatePassword();
    var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");
   passwordText.value = password;
};

// Add event listener to generate button
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword);
```

I was provide the button code from class. so I'm pretty sure that is good code. Although it seems like that is where the errors seem to be coming in.  I'm also not sure why the newPassword.push has an error.

Comment: Have you defined `newPassword` somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I did. I actually found out what is was doing wrong. It was a typo.